# Puppet - Pass hash as class argument(s)

Tags: puppet

Trying to do something like this:

```
# nodes.pp
node 'dev-a-1.sn1.vpc1.example.com' inherits project_j1n_sn1_vpc1_dev {

    class { 'custom::core':
        overrides => {
            'openssh' => {'settings' => {'external_access' => 'true'}}, # Allow direct mounting for dev
            'rsyslog' => {'settings' => {'role' => 'node', 'filters' => {'php' => {'target' => 'remote'}, 'mail' => {'target' => 'remote'}}}}
        }
    }
}

# custom::core
class custom::core($overrides = {}) {

    if (has_key($overrides, 'openssh')) {

        $settings = $overrides['openssh']['settings']

        # Doesn't work
        create_resources('openssh', $settings)

        # Doesn't work
        class { 'openssh': $settings }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to call a class and pass a hash as the arguments?

Puppet/Puppetmaster v2.7.26-1 (Centos 6.7)

Comment: This doesn't answer your question directly, but have you considered using hiera? If you're looking for a way to pass parameters to nodes, with overrides based on environment and node name, that's exactly what hiera is for. Once I got my head around it, it has worked well for me. http://docs.puppetlabs.com/hiera/latest/

Comment: Ya I use hiera, I just don't want to use hiera to dictate node behavior, that's what the manifests are supposed to do. I ended up just doing a bunch of conditionals which I will post in a few days if there are no other responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A co-worker of mine had come up with a good solution to something similar in the old `2+` days of puppet. Utilized `create_resources` for this.

http://www.followski.com/quick-note-how-to-use-create_resources-to-initialize-a-class-in-puppet/

your code can look something like this:

#### nodes.pp

```
node 'dev-a-1.sn1.vpc1.example.com' inherits project_j1n_sn1_vpc1_dev {

    class { 'custom::core':
        overrides => {
            'openssh' => {'settings' => {'external_access' => 'true'}}, # Allow direct mounting for dev
            'rsyslog' => {'settings' => {'role' => 'node', 'filters' => {'php' => {'target' => 'remote'}, 'mail' => {'target' => 'remote'}}}}
        }
    }
}
```

#### custom::core

```
class custom::core($overrides = {}) {

    if (has_key($overrides, 'openssh')) {

        $settings = $overrides['openssh']['settings']

        create_resources('class', { 'openssh' => $settings })
    }
}
```

You will notice that in the example linked above it looks like `create_resources('class', $params)`, but that assuming you have a hash with a key being the class name (ie `openssh`) and its value being the params to set. The example I state above essentially does the same thing.

Your node definition can also be look like this:

```
node 'dev-a-1.sn1.vpc1.example.com' inherits project_j1n_sn1_vpc1_dev {

    class { 'custom::core':
        overrides => {
            'openssh' => {'external_access' => 'true'}, # Allow direct mounting for dev
            'rsyslog' => {'role' => 'node', 'filters' => {'php' => {'target' => 'remote'}, 'mail' => {'target' => 'remote'}}}
        }
    }
}
```

and your class something like this:

```
class custom::core($overrides = {}) {
  if (has_key($overrides, 'openssh')) {
    create_resources('class', {'openssh' => $overrides['openssh'])
  }

  if (has_key($overrides, 'rsyslog')) {
    create_resources('class', {'rsyslog' => $overrides['rsyslog'])
  }
}
```

I think you get the point by now.

We used this quite often a few years ago. You may want to consider moving towards an upgrade of your puppet infrastructure however.

Hope this helps, or at least points you in the right direction.

Comment: Siiiiick.... I'll try this.... You should see the custom::core manifest as it stands, conditional hell...

Comment: @MikePurcell I believe it. this was pretty standard for us while trying to implement roles and profiles before it was a best practice. if you upgrade in the near future your puppet dev/admin life will be much easier.

Comment: Which version are you guys running? It took a LONG time to beat 2.7.x into submission and I don't want to do the port work anytime soon, maybe after a funding round, but for now it works great. Node manifests are clean and light, and the code in .pp manifests is heavily re-useable.

Comment: @MikePurcell we are still on PE 3.8 (not sure the puppet community version that corresponds... version schemes change so often at puppetlabs). one thing, in puppet 3+ (i think), node inheritance is deprecated, so no more `node 'foo' inherits 'bar'` kind of stuff. they force the `roles` and `profiles` paradigm.

Comment: Nice, are you guys planning to migrate to PE 4? They move so fast on versions that we are still deciding when to upgrade.

Answer (score 5):

There is a way in Puppet 4+.

```
class { 'ssh':
  * => $settings
}
```

Learn all about it on [roidelapluie's blog](https://roidelapluie.be/blog/2015/09/15/puppet-4-create-resources/).

Comment: Nice. Ill try this out. Er nvm... still running puppet 2.7. Can't upgrade right now would take forever to migrate all the manifests...